# Login Activity In Android Not Running

Tags: android

My android application which accepts login is not ruuning.It gives me the following error  in logcat.I am not able to correct it.Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks In advance

```
04-22 17:42:55.786: W/dalvikvm(1353): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-22 17:42:55.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1353): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 17:42:55.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1353): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abhineel.studentinfo/com.abhineel.studentinfo.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 17:42:55.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-22 17:42:55.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-22 17:42:55.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-22 17:42:55.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-22 17:42:55.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 17:42:55.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 17:42:55.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-22 17:42:55.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 17:42:55.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 17:42:55.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-22 17:42:55.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-22 17:42:55.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 17:42:55.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1353): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 17:42:55.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at com.abhineel.studentinfo.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:67)
04-22 17:42:55.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-22 17:42:55.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-22 17:42:55.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-22 17:42:55.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     ... 11 more
```

I am posting the entire code.If there is any other error apart from that particular line that logcat shows then please help me with that also.My LoginActivity.java file
package com.abhineel.studentinfo;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit, mRegister;

     // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //php login script location:

    //localhost :
    //testing on your device
    //put your local ip instead,  on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
    //or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
   // private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/login.php";

    //testing on Emulator:
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:80/androidProj/login.php";

  //testing from a real server:
    //private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.yourdomain.com/webservice/login.php";

    //JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //setup input fields
        user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usn);
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

        //setup buttons
        mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);

        //register listeners
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(LoginActivity.this);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(LoginActivity.this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.login:
                new AttemptLogin().execute();
            break;
        case R.id.register:
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

         /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                       LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ReadComments.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Show the line number 67, from file LoginActivity.java

Comment: read your stacktrace !

Comment: findViewById returns null if id isn't found in the layout! Adding an OnClickListener on null ==> NPE

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see there a couple things to look at.

I would recommend using an interface with a callback method to control when doInBackground actually completes. It could be added to your AsyncTask class like:

```
class AttemptLogin //extends AsyncTask etc {

    static interface Callback {
        void onComplete(String response); //could be any data like JsonObject,etc
    }

    Callback callback;        

    // in constructor take in instance of interface
    AtemptLogin(Callback l_callback){
        callback = l_callback;
    }

    // in do onbackground

    callback.onComplete(response);
}

// From activity
new AttemptLogin(new AttemptLogin.Callback(
    @Overide
    onComplete(String response){
        //handle response dismiss dialog etc
    })
);
```

Also you are referencing the form widgets from the async task it may be a better idea to pass those in by reference. In your code you are declaring AsyncTask with 3 types , I would read the documentation on AsyncTask about the three generics in takes in  and how they are used. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You also have the activity itself as the on click listener. This is partly related but you need to be able to handle the events when the webservice returns and then execute your intents like you are doing in the register button. You are currently doing this from doInBackground which will cause a null pointer exception.